# How to pass a file from a remote host to another remote host in java?

Tags: java, linux, unix

I have been working on an application that uses JSCH to scp and transfer a file to another directory in the same server. However, I want to be able to transfer a file from one remote host to another remote host in an automated way. Below is the code I use to make the call. I have tried using other scp commands such as:  `scp [options] username1@source_host:directory1/filename1 username2@destination_host:directory2/filename2`. It works when testing it on the server itself but when I try to incorporate it into the code below, it passes back an error.

**CODE:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args){

    String array [] = {"robert.txt","ops1axv@gaalpltclu00029.linux.us.ams1907.com:/tmp"};

    if(array.length!=2){
      System.err.println("usage: java ScpTo file1 user@remotehost:file2");
      System.exit(-1);
    }      

    FileInputStream fis=null;
    try{

      String lfile=array[0];
      String user=array[1].substring(0, array[1].indexOf('@'));
      array[1]=array[1].substring(array[1].indexOf('@')+1);
      String host=array[1].substring(0, array[1].indexOf(':'));
      String rfile=array[1].substring(array[1].indexOf(':')+1);

      System.out.println("RFile: " + rfile );
      System.out.println("Lfile: " + lfile);

      JSch jsch=new JSch();
      Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

      // username and password will be given via UserInfo interface.
      UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
      session.setUserInfo(ui);
      session.connect();

      boolean ptimestamp = true;

      // exec 'scp -t rfile' remotely
      String command="scp " + (ptimestamp ? "-p" :"") +" -t "+rfile;
      Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
      ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

      // get I/O streams for remote scp
      OutputStream out=channel.getOutputStream();
      InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();

      channel.connect();

      if(checkAck(in)!=0){
    System.exit(0);
      }

      File _lfile = new File(lfile);

      if(ptimestamp){
        command="T"+(_lfile.lastModified()/1000)+" 0";
        // The access time should be sent here,
        // but it is not accessible with JavaAPI ;-<
        command+=(" "+(_lfile.lastModified()/1000)+" 0\n"); 
        out.write(command.getBytes()); out.flush();
        if(checkAck(in)!=0){
      System.exit(0);
        }
      }

      // send "C0644 filesize filename", where filename should not include '/'
      long filesize=_lfile.length();
      command="C0644 "+filesize+" ";
      if(lfile.lastIndexOf('/')>0){
        command+=lfile.substring(lfile.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
      }
      else{
        command+=lfile;
      }
      command+="\n";
      out.write(command.getBytes()); out.flush();
      if(checkAck(in)!=0){
    System.exit(0);
      }

      // send a content of lfile
      fis=new FileInputStream(lfile);
      byte[] buf=new byte[1024];
      while(true){
        int len=fis.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
    if(len<=0) break;
        out.write(buf, 0, len); //out.flush();
      }
      fis.close();
      fis=null;
      // send '\0'
      buf[0]=0; out.write(buf, 0, 1); out.flush();
      if(checkAck(in)!=0){
    System.exit(0);
      }
      out.close();

      channel.disconnect();
      session.disconnect();

      System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
      try{if(fis!=null)fis.close();}catch(Exception ee){}
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @NicholasK Im sorry let me rephrase, there is no error.  Though in the beginning of my code, when I try to enter " scp [options] username1@source_host:directory1/filename1 username2@destination_host:directory2/filename2" into the array. It will not compile, and I just dont know it which way to edit my script in order to get it to work.

Comment: Any reason you are using an array?

Comment: @NicholasK I found it easier to break apart and identify each part. Also, when I tried using a string variable and setting the command to the variable.I didn't get the desired result. It just failed to compile.

Comment: Your code is compiling fine. Not really sure what the issue is, if you could do elaborate further.

Comment: @NicholasK No problem, but you tried the code adding the scp command that I typed out and it works?

Comment: @NicholasK Maybe I just have to go back and see where I went wrong and try added the scp command in another way.

Comment: Please paste that statement here. Your previous comment was not clear.